# Uitableview re sizing in storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, storyboard

Im using uitableview with navigation controller in storyboard,while adding the tableview cell the last row data is hidden back in the toolbar.How i can show the last row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to `viewDidLoad`

```
UIEdgeInsets myInsets = {0, 0, 44, 0};
self.tableView.contentInset = myInsets;
```